# Using a single Google Drive as central data server

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I just did a bit of research on the Google Drive API for Android and I was wondering if this was possible.

Is there a way to have all users of an app upload something to a **central** Google Drive account to be able to share the data?

I was thinking of an app where users could upload links to YouTube videos and other users could see those links, but I'm not really sure if that is even possible with Google Drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have all users of an app upload something to a central Google Drive account to be able to share the data?

Google Drive API isn't made for that.

I think that what you are looking for is [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/)

> Cloud Storage for Firebase lets you upload and share user generated content, such as images and video, which allows you to build rich media content into your apps. Your data is stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, an exabyte scale object storage solution with high availability and global redundancy. Cloud Storage lets you securely upload these files directly from mobile devices and web browsers, handling spotty networks with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Google drive api doesn’t provide any documentation for the use case which are asking for. A drive permission can also be a constraint to generic usage of the single drive account.